# Python not summing a list

Tags: python, sum

I cannot get python to sum a list. No matter what I try, I cannot get the following code to run. Can someone please help me?

```
A = []
while 1<2:
    i = input("Enter a number")
    if int(i) == -1:
        s = sum(A)
        print(s)
        break
    elif int(i) != -1: 
        A.append(i)
```

Comment: You say you can not get it to run? What have you tried? What happens when you try to run it? Is there an error? Please read this page to learn how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.x**
input "i" needs to be converted to an int before adding to  list "A"

```
A =[]
while 1<2:
    i=int(input("Enter a number"))
    if i==-1:
        s=sum(A)
        print(s)
        break
    elif i!=-1: A.append(i)
```

**Python 2.x**

No need to convert input to an int.

```
A =[]
while 1<2:
i=(input("Enter a number"))
if i==-1:
    print(type(A))
    s=sum(A)
    print(s)
    break
elif i!=-1: A.append(i)
```